# How can I use O_DIRECT or O_SYNC on an external SD card with Android KitKat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I work for a company that makes an SD memory card that includes a hardware encryption engine. We interact with the encryption module by writing/reading to a special file.

Starting with KitKat, the `O_DIRECT` flag does not seem to be supported on the external SD card. Without `O_DIRECT or O_SYNC` support, the OS will returned cached data when we read the encryption engine's response from the SD card (via our special file).

Is there a procedure to open a file on the eternal SD card, read/write, with either `O_DIRECT or O_SYNC`?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/stressapptest/+/android-cts-4.2_r2%5E%5E!/ and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-kernel/5PWHui9cPcI : I'd say it needs vendor MMC driver support and it's not always there. You might be able to flush buffers like in first link to get the intended behavior

Comment: I work for a SD-based SE company. KitKat's O_DIRECT removal is killing us too. 

Right now, there is no solution for this issue.
Please advise your customers not to upgrade to KitKat.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root-access to your phone you can write a 1 to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches to clear the page cache (see http://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches). After that command the next read on the sdcard will return the non-cached data.

For stock-devices (where you have no permission to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches) there is a issue in the AOSP (you may star it):
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67406

Comment: It's for stock devices. Rooting is not an option since you can't tell all customers to root the phone.