# open file with flag O_DIRECT not working from android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-ndk

In Android ndk, I want to bypass cache while reading and writing in file. So, I'm trying to open a file with the O_DIRECT flag.

```
fd = open((char *)filepath, O_RDWR | O_DIRECT);
getting below error
fd : -1
Error : 22 Invalid argument
```

This problem is coming from android version 4.4.2, Looks like platform has blocked this flag.

Does anyone has any suggestion to bypass cache while reading and writing. 
To solve this problem I have tried using O_SYNC flag which does not bypass cache but guarantees sync.

```
fd = open((char *)filepath, O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
```

But this doesnt work as expected it is adding delay in gettting expected data in read file.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, I think I cant share because its something related to business logic. But I am not sure why google is behaving little bit weird in making platform stable. We can welcome that they have limited access to sd card and added sandboxing for each app on sd card, but not like limiting O_DIRECT.

Comment: Maybe this depends on the file path and the file system on that path. I see error 22 for `O_DIRECT` in a different scenario: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-ndk/wi2j2LBwCjw

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873726/how-can-i-use-o-direct-or-o-sync-on-an-external-sd-card-with-android-kitkat